# Passing a dictionary from view controllers

Tags: iphone

In one of my Navigation view controllers I build an array of dictionaries to display in a table. Based on which one I select I then remove the dictionary from the array using 
NSDictionary *notice = [notices objectAtIndex: roomIndex];

I create the new view controller using 
Feed *notice_view = [[Notice alloc] initWithObject: notice];

I push the navigation view controller and I've implemented initWithObject which takes a Dictionary.

I release the notice and notice_view and all this works fine but if I selected go back, select it go back about the third or forth time the whole app crashes. If I dont release both of them it works fine no problems what so ever, except of course the memory leaks.If i only release one of them, either of them, it fails again. What gives? Should I not be using initWithObject or should I be passing it in some other way? I've also tried using autorelease but with the same result.

Comment: It might be easier to get help if you post some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

notice - you should not release, since you don't own the object(you are just using a object which is returned from NSArray) else retain this object when you retrieve the object from NSArray and release it later stage.

notice_view - as per you explanation I don't see any issue with releasing, I am assuming you don't have any reference to this object from other part of the code.

Comment: notice - of course makes sense.

k, I tried to just release notice_view which im sure I had tried with the same results but now its working fine -_-

Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: I figured out what happened while I was stuffing around which has raised another question. If I declare a Dictionary in the Notice_view and copy the passed dictionary into it, if I say dictionary = it fails after the third go, if I say self.dictionary = its Kosher. I came from other languages so excuse me if this is noob or wrong

Comment: dictionary = it -> in this case your keeping pointer referring but you are not owning the object(if you have want to own the object dictionary = [it retain])

self.dictionary = its - > self.dictionary in this case you are using  default setter method defined using 'property'(objective C 2.0) which add a retain count to the object(make it own by the object)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you'll want to get rid of [selectedNotice release], since there doesn't seem to be a corresponding -retain call in there.